# Is there a way of getting an Uber API authorization code whose expiry period is beyond the default 10 minutes?

Tags: oauth, access-token, uber-api

I would like to request Uber cabs on behalf of an Uber user, but first the user needs to permit the app to have access to his profile and permit the app to send requests on his behalf. However, the returned authorization code that I can use to get the access token in order to send user requests on their behalf is only valid for 10 minutes and my requirement needs me to send requests even 24 hours later.

Is there a way to get a permanent authorization code or access token that never expires or at least one that lasts for a long period, e.g. a month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) says as follows in [4.1.2. Authorization Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2):

> **code**
>
> REQUIRED.  The authorization code generated by the authorization server.  The authorization code MUST expire shortly after it is issued to mitigate the risk of leaks.  **A maximum authorization code lifetime of 10 minutes is RECOMMENDED.**  The client MUST NOT use the authorization code

Therefore, it is hopeless to expect an authorization code with longer lifetime than 10 minutes. So, you should exchange an authorization code for an access token at the [token endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2) immediately using the way described in [4.1.3. Access Token Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3).

If Uber's authorization server issues a refresh token when it issues an access token, you can expect it has longer lifetime than an access token. You can use a refresh token at the token endpoint in order to get a new access token. See [6. Refreshing an Access Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6) for details.

If lifetime of access tokens and refresh tokens issued by Uber is less than 24 hours, you have to change the flow of your application.